# How to run a script when Night Light is triggered

Tags: 22.04, themes, gnome-shell, dbus, night-light

I'm not asking how to enable/disable Night Light light via cli. (`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled`)

I'd like to run a script each time Night Light activates or deactivates. (And I assume that there will only be triggers if Night Light is actually **enabled.**)

One simple example: Run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'` when Night Light **activates** and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-light'` each time it **deactivates.**

Is there a way to run a custom script on Night Light trigger?

Comment: Hi @Majal. Are you ok with an extension? this is just the beginning. If you are Ok then I will try.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Z0e.gif I have created an extension for gnome-shell v46, this should work in gnome-shell v45 too. I gus 22.04 uses gnome-shell v44 rite. for gnome-shell v44 some tweaking might required for the code.

Comment: Hi @PRATAP! Sure anything that works is welcome. Of course, the less dependence the better. Or if you can get part of your code that actually fires during the trigger, and how that can be implemented to run a custom script, that's welcome too.

Comment: Ok, I will give you the code in the answer section in the next couple of hours, I will highlight how you can run a custom script in it.

Comment: I think Ubuntu 22.04 uses gnome-shell v42. I don't have that version to test, but I tried refactoring its code. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/script-night-light. Try it and give me what errors it is showing, once the extension runs, then I will refactor the code to run a script.

Comment: One could 1) Rename the `night-light` executable to `night-light.org`; 2) Provide your own `bash` script `night-light` which a) Does what you want; b) Invokes `night-light.org`; c) Does what you want.